# Ncrack symtax to run multiple IP's and how to add threads and time? CL=5,cd700ms?

Tags: syntax

i use ncrack for windows
Ncrack syntax,how to run multiple IP's and add threads and waiting time?

I use this ordinary syntax with no threads and no waiting time and ncrack rate up to 40

```
ncrack -vv -d7 -U users.txt -P pass1.txt -iL ips.txt -p rdp
```

Now i try to use few threads and time using this syntax, i add 5 threads and 700 ms,ncrack rate 40,the same that means no effect
So my question is:how to add multiple IPs, 5 threads and 700 ms waiting time

> ncrack -v -d7 -U users.txt -P pass1.txt -iL ips.txt CL=5,cd=700ms -p
>   rdp

I also tried this and i received :CL=5,cd=700 ms not suported so ignoring...

> ncrack -vv -d7 -U users.txt -P pass1.txt -iL ips.txt -p
>   rdp,CL=5,cd=700ms